# .htaccess Redirect rule causing loop on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website with multiple products with similar url structure. Something like: 
`www.site.com/product-test-yellow
www.site.com/product-test-red
www.site.com/product-test-blue`

I need to redirect (301) every url starting with:
`www.site.com/product-test-`
to a new product page, for example:
`www.site.com/product-test-new`

I've tried this in my .htaccess file but I still errors:

`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product-test-(.*) \/product-new\/ [L,R=301,NC]`

Thanks

Comment: It's probably conflicting with another redirect. That code alone will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a loop problem because the destination url is similar to the original url.
Problem solved using classic link structure in wordpress (ex. index.php/?p=3221)